# how to keep alive in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE%3Awipro')
r.content
bt = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
span = bt.find_all('span',class_="pr")
span[0].contents
span1= span[0].contents
res = span1[1].contents
chg = bt.find_all('span', class_="chg")
res1 = chg[0].contents[0]
res2 = chg[1].contents[0]
print "Last Trading Price :" + str(res)
print "change:"              + str(res1)
print "Change in: %"          + str(res2)
```

This is my program.when run this program this only show real time data and quit .i want to keep alive it

Comment: What do you mean by *keep alive it*? You need to be clearer in your expectations. The program should not quit? What should happen instead?

Comment: i what to keep alive request.when we run the program this show me that time data.i want data conntinue ...i hope you understand what is say..my english not so wall

Comment: No, I don't understand what you mean. HTTP is a stateless protocol, there is no 'alive' here. It *sounds* as if you want your requests to be repeated to show changes over time, but that is a very broad subject; we cannot help you figure out strategies to do that here, we can only help you implement a strategy once you picked one.

Comment: i want to connection keep alive from google finance

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`requests.session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) session when making your request.

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
r = session.get('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE%3Awipro')
r.content
...
r = session.get('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE%3Awipro')
```

The connection will be kept open and subsequent requests to the same server using the same session will use that same connection. Note that there might be timeouts involved at the remote server which may elect to close the connection after a short(ish) period of time (e.g. 5-15 seconds)